# @property applied to global (modul) function

Tags: python

In some python module there are functions decorated with property attribute:

```
@property
def _Foo_bar(self):
```

What does the above declaration mean? Do the underscores '_' signify anything?

Comment: A Python tutorial (or the user manual) may be a better place to find out than asking this on StackOverflow.

Comment: @jochen It doesn't say anything about applying '@property' to functions defined outside any class

Answer (score 0):

people are down voting because it doesn't look like you researched your question before posting it.  You can see the documentation for you `@property` decorator here: [python decorator docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property)

To answer your question, the `@property` is normally used for your class properties.

```
# this should work in py2 and py3
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self._a = None

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, val):
        self._a = val

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = Foo()
    foo.a = "some value"
    print(foo.a)
```

the `_` in the `self._a` doesn't do anything to the code but instead considers it hidden.  This means that you "should" not be accessing them directly. You could do something like,

```
foo._a = "some value"
```

but you are then bypassing the intent of the code.  Meybe you want to have read only access to that variable (code above without the `@a.setter` method).

Answer (score 0):

A **property** is a descriptor object.
Here is a brief explanation from python docs

> In general, a descriptor is an object attribute with “binding behavior”, one whose attribute access has been overridden by methods in the descriptor protocol. Those methods are **get**(), **set**(), and **delete**(). If any of those methods are defined for an object, it is said to be a descriptor.
>   
>   The default behavior for attribute access is to get, set, or delete the attribute from an object’s dictionary. For instance, a.x has a lookup chain starting with a.**dict**['x'], then type(a).**dict**['x'], and continuing through the base classes of type(a) excluding metaclasses. If the looked-up value is an object defining one of the descriptor methods, then Python may override the default behavior and invoke the descriptor method instead. Where this occurs in the precedence chain depends on which descriptor methods were defined. Note that descriptors are only invoked for new style objects or classes (a class is new style if it inherits from object or type).

Simply, if you want to access some object's attribute but to run some code e.g. for type checking you can use properties and pass (get, set, delete) functions to alter the default behavior of attribute access.

**Underscore** in used conventionally to denote private attibutes.